# I pressed something and now many edges do not appear in edit mode

Tags: modeling

in blender 2.8 I pressed a button unintentionally, and as a consequence the mesh specifically only for this object had this change in which many edges do not appear even when I select the face that is still there for some reason does not appear

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi there :) . A possible explaination for this is that you might have either triangulated the faces or you might've applied a decimate modifier. (As far as i can tell)

Comment: If there are hidden edges in edit mode press Alt+H to un-hide them.